# Defining relative percentage frame limits in a postgres window frame

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a query where I am trying to find the average of energy consumption over a group of service locations that each fall within ±5% of each other for a particular month. I know that range and rows function can't define a particular range of numbers and instead use preceding and following clauses but how can I write this query to suit my needs?

```
WITH energy_consumption_cte AS (
    SELECT
        sl.id,
        sl.sqft,
        SUM(CASE WHEN dl.log_label = 'energy use' THEN dl.value END) AS monthly_consumption
    FROM
        serv_location sl
    INNER JOIN
        device d ON d.service_loc_id = sl.id
    INNER JOIN
        device_log dl ON dl.device_id = d.id
    WHERE
        dl."timestamp" >= '2022-08-01 00:01:00.000'::timestamp
        AND dl."timestamp" < '2022-09-01 00:01:00.000'::timestamp
        AND sl.sqft IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
        sl.id, sl.sqft
)

SELECT
    id,
    sqft,
    monthly_consumption,
    (monthly_consumption / AVG(monthly_consumption) OVER w) * 100 
    AS average_monthly_for_sqft_range
FROM
    energy_consumption_cte
window w as (PARTITION BY sqft ORDER BY sqft range between 
    ROUND(sqft * 0.95) and ROUND(sqft * 1.05))
ORDER BY
    sqft ASC;
```

Comment: Could you please add a `create` statement for tables involved with an `insert` of some samples, along with a desired output you'd like this to return based on those samples?

Comment: @Zegarek I am trying to find the total energy consumption during the month of August 2022, as a percent to the average monthly consumption for the other locations that have a similar square footage (meaning, ±5% higher or lower square footage). Meaning for for a sl.id of sqft=800, it will calculate the average energy consumption for all sls with 760 <= sqft <= 840 and find the percent as monthly_consumption of that sl divided by average of the group of 760 <= sqft <= 840 locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window frame [`range` mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) *can* define particular range. To use an aggregate function that'll include values from records 5% up/down from the current one, you should think `range between 0.05*sqft preceding and 0.05*sqft following`. Problem is, you can't use variables there.

> In the ***offset*** `PRECEDING` and ***offset*** `FOLLOWING` frame options, the ***offset*** must be an expression not containing any variables, aggregate functions, or window functions.

If you try to refer to the `sqft` column/field, you'll get this:

> ```
> ERROR:  argument of RANGE must not contain variables
> LINE 27:              RANGE BETWEEN sqft*0.05 PRECEDING
>                                     ^
> ```

You can work around that limitation by first calculating % change from row to row using [`lag()` or `lead()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE), then collecting that into a stepping `sum()`, so that it maintains the initial order of `sqft`. Once you have that, you can use constant offset in the frame clause to reach 5% back and forth. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wqz-LnjC)

```sql
WITH energy_consumption_cte AS (
    SELECT sl.id,
           sl.sqft,
           SUM(dl.value)filter(where dl.log_label='energy use') AS monthly_consumption
    FROM serv_location sl
    INNER JOIN device d ON d.service_loc_id = sl.id
    INNER JOIN device_log dl ON dl.device_id = d.id
    WHERE dl."timestamp" >= '2022-08-01 00:01:00.000'::timestamp
      AND dl."timestamp" < '2022-09-01 00:01:00.000'::timestamp
      AND sl.sqft IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY sl.id, sl.sqft 
),square_footage_steps_cte AS (
    SELECT *, 1-lag(sqft,1,sqft)over(order by sqft)/sqft::numeric AS sqft_step
    FROM energy_consumption_cte
    ORDER BY sqft ASC
),square_footage_steps_cumulative_cte AS (
    SELECT *, sum(sqft_step)over(order by sqft) AS sqft_step_sum
    FROM square_footage_steps_cte
    ORDER BY sqft ASC)
SELECT id,
       sqft,
       monthly_consumption,
       AVG(monthly_consumption) OVER w AS average_monthly_for_sqft_range,
       array_agg(id)over w as rows_in_frame
FROM square_footage_steps_cumulative_cte 
WINDOW w as (ORDER BY sqft_step_sum
             RANGE BETWEEN 0.05 PRECEDING
                   AND     0.05 FOLLOWING)
ORDER BY sqft ASC;
```

| id | sqft | monthly_consumption | average_monthly_for_sqft_range | rows_in_frame |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 400 | 700.0000000000000000 | {1,2} |
| 2 | 105 | 1000 | 1000.0000000000000000 | {1,2,3} |
| 3 | 110 | 1600 | 1600.0000000000000000 | {2,3,4} |
| 4 | 115 | 2200 | 1900.0000000000000000 | {3,4} |
| 5 | 200 | 2800 | 3100.0000000000000000 | {5,6} |
| 6 | 210 | 3400 | 3100.0000000000000000 | {5,6} |

Comment: That was an interesting solution, I tried using your query and had to typecast a few things to suit my needs but it doesn't calculate the correct outputs for this particular case: [image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/819937399806099486/1179162327170433055/image.png?ex=6578c77e&is=6566527e&hm=94c157457460a2d2f678fffdcc998e54e29506f26c158990441a58bc18ea1ef7&). I am looking more into what might be the case but so far the data appears clean and I am at my ends. Even so, I loved your use of lag(), thanks!

Comment: I had to guess your schema based on your query, so I'm not surprised it didn't immediately match the real thing :) If you share the `create` and `insert` statements with mock/fake/sample data that resembles the set that's causing trouble, you can edit the question and add it there. That, or what exactly you did to the query, I won't be able to guess that easily.

Comment: In your picture I'm missing the `array_agg()` I showed above in the last column, which could help you figure out which rows ended up in a frame together and thus which values ended up entering `avg()`. Also, are you sure you didn't re-add `partition by` (that I intentionally removed)? 830 is within the 5% range, but it will still end up outside the frame if you `partition by sqft`

Comment: I ran a generator function so there's thousands of lines of mock data. As for the result, I removed the array_agg part just because, here's the output with it: [image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/819937399806099486/1179195480140431473/image.png?ex=6578e65e&is=6566715e&hm=a7211fe5087afda5fd009dfa796802f5a294c65a4a85cf6d0e764a148eed7c69&). Here's the query I used, just has some basic casting: [image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/819937399806099486/1179196834254696518/image.png?ex=6578e7a1&is=656672a1&hm=d195991e2c8995b1e6c9b1cea92a45acf83662644a2da854ba4fdb2162e7b25b&)

Comment: I found the error, apparently sqft was defined as an int so the result of 1-lag(sqft, 1, sqft) over(order by sqft)/sqft was coming out as a rounded int and not float, causing errors in everything later on. I typecasted the thing as: 1-lag(sqft, 1, sqft) over(order by sqft)/sqft::float and it worked lol.