# Grouping by using cumulative sum

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Input**: consecutive numbers from 1 to 100 - 1,2,3,...,100

**Desired output:**

- 1st group: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 -> sum 15 (not bigger than 20)
- 2nd group: 6, 7 -> sum 13 (not bigger than 20)
- 3rd group: 8, 9 -> sum 17 (not bigger than 20)
- 4th group: 10 -> sum 10 (not bigger than 20)
- 5th group: 11 -> sum 11 (not bigger than 20)
- ...
- nth-1 group: 99 -> sum 99 (bigger than 20, but only one element)
- nth group: 100 -> sum 100 (bigger than 20, but only one element)

```
SELECT array_agg(n)
FROM generate_series(1, 100) as n
GROUP BY ... -- TODO -> Here's go magic grouping or other magic tricks
```

So I have consecutive numbers from 1 to 100, and I would like to group them in that way that sum in group is not bigger than 20 (if single number is bigger than 20 than new group with one element).

Edit:
Max number (in the example `100`) and max group's sum (in the example `20`) are dynamic, so I cannot use hard coded solution.

Comment: Hmm, maybe ``WITH RECURSIVE`` will help with that

Comment: `NTILE()` anyone?

Comment: OK, the result after 19 still is confusing, what, it should not be bigger than 20, but ..... (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/_naTkxXV )

Comment: Ah, you want to have this, but then written nicer.... : https://dbfiddle.uk/ilc37jU3

Comment: Sum of elements in each group shouldn't be greater than ``20``.Exceptions are number from 21 to 100, for them must be individuals group (practically from number ``10`` all groups will have only one element).

Comment: Sounds like a [`range` window frame clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS). Similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77566553/5298879).

Comment: I deleted my answer because of the EDIT.... (the question was changed to `100` (top of range) and `20` (max value in group) being dynamic....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a recursive query and 2 `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END`, you can get a more compact solution than the other answers:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE A(GroupNum, n, RollingSum) AS (
    /* Start with the minimum element */
    SELECT 1, 1, 1
    UNION ALL
    /* Add the next element, but first test if it can be added within the current group */
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN RollingSum + T.n > 20 THEN GroupNum + 1 ELSE GroupNum END,
        T.n,
        CASE WHEN RollingSum + T.n > 20 THEN T.n ELSE RollingSum + T.n END
    FROM A
    JOIN generate_series(1, 100) AS T(n) ON a.n + 1 = T.n
)
SELECT GroupNum, n, SUM(n) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupNum)
FROM A
ORDER BY GroupNum, n
```

An alternative to the main query would be if you want to group records from the same `GroupNum`. In that case, use:

```sql
SELECT GroupNum, ARRAY_AGG(n ORDER BY n), SUM(n)
FROM A
GROUP BY GroupNum
ORDER BY GroupNum
```

---

Notes:

- You can of course replace `generate_series(1, 100) AS T(n)` by a proper table/view.
- The initial `SELECT 1,1,1` may also be replaced by a query that uses a proper table and selects the first element of the list such as:

  ```sql
  SELECT 1, MIN(n), MIN(n)
  FROM T
  ```
- If the values inside (the real table) `T` are not separated by 1, you will need to create a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n)` to turn it into consecutive values.
- A slightly complicated optimization can be done in the event you run this query with many more records and another limit value `v`. If you find the first `n >= v /2`, you know that any subsequent `n` is going to be in its own group.
  If your successive `n` are separated by 1, any `n > ceil(v / 2)` will be in its own group. It is not necessarily true if they are separated by more than 1, e.g. if you had only odd numbers, the first `n >= 10` is 11, but you may and in fact will group `9 + 11 <= 20` together.

  You can use this fact to avoid processing the corresponding records in the recursive CTE and add them back with a `UNION ALL` in the main query.

---

Edit to answer the comment about "random" arrays.

Courtesy of Zegarek, I have taken the function definition he left me and turned it into the one below, that will let you input any array.
Compared to the query above, I have added a `ROWNUM() OVER (ORDER BY n)` as a helper for the `JOIN` in the recursive query.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION groups_up_to_sum( 
                                 IN GroupSumLimit BIGINT,
                                 IN ValueArray ANYCOMPATIBLEARRAY
                                )
  RETURNS TABLE(GroupNum INT, n INT[], SumOfN BIGINT) AS 
$f$
WITH RECURSIVE A(GroupNum, n, RollingSum, r) AS (
    /* Start with the minimum element */
    SELECT 1, n, n, r
    FROM T
    WHERE r = 1
    UNION ALL
    /* Add the next element, but first test if it can be added within the current group */
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN RollingSum + T.n > GroupSumLimit THEN GroupNum + 1 ELSE GroupNum END,
        T.n,
        CASE WHEN RollingSum + T.n > GroupSumLimit THEN T.n ELSE RollingSum + T.n END,
        T.r
    FROM A
    JOIN T ON A.r + 1 = T.r
), T(n , r) AS (
    SELECT n, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n)
    FROM UNNEST(ValueArray) AS Aux(n)
)
SELECT GroupNum, ARRAY_AGG(n ORDER BY n), SUM(n)
FROM A
GROUP BY GroupNum
$f$ 
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Usage:

```sql
/* Array from 1 to 100, group sum value <= 20 (= initial case from the question) */
SELECT *
FROM groups_up_to_sum(20, (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(n) FROM generate_series(1,100) AS T(n)))
ORDER BY GroupNum;

/* Odd numbers from 1 to 100k, group sum value <= 4000 */
SELECT *
FROM groups_up_to_sum(4000, (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(n) FROM generate_series(1, 100000, 2) AS T(n)))
ORDER BY GroupNum;

/* Custom, unsorted array, group sum value <= 20 */
SELECT *
FROM groups_up_to_sum(20, ARRAY[11,1,3,9,6,7,8,5,20])
ORDER BY GroupNum;

/* Array built from a select */
SELECT *
FROM groups_up_to_sum(20, (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(SomeIntField) FROM SomeTable))
ORDER BY GroupNum;
```

Comment: Very clean, well thought-out and explained, big +1. Without the routine-wrapping it's not *dynamic* as per OP's requirement, but I understand that obfuscates a bit how brief and elegant the core part of the solution is, so feel free to rollback or overwrite my edit.

Comment: @Atmo The solution is great. Could you please elaborate, how to solve problem for non consecutive numbers - just random numbers?

Comment: Sure, done. I provided the function definition for this case along with some calls for illustration. The last example takes values from a table. I cannot guarantee it will work with millions of records but I tried with a table with more than 84k records on my laptop (execution in 0.5s). If you feel you are limited, since a function cannot be passed a table, you will need to either extract the function body and adjust the `T(n)` CTE definition or change the function signature to take a table name/query text, and use `EXECUTE` to run the "dynamic" query.

Answer (score 3):

*Note:* This answer addresses the original problem of summing over a well-defined input of consecutive integers starting at 1. It does not consider the later added question about arbitrary inputs.

The natural solution is a trivial loop passing over the sequence in order and a counter that increments every time the next number exceeds the bracket size. And the naive query in SQL mimics that patterns with a straightforward recursive query. This approach works by generating a narrow list of possible consecutive series of maximal length at least two and then chaining them together recursively. The single value series are appended at the end.

This query was also created with efficiency in mind and minimizing the recursion depth. It appears to work well with relatively large inputs. The bracketing size (which is 20 in the example) is really the only factor in the size of the search space. With many input combinations there will be a lot of single-value ranges ("degenerate" values) padding out the list. Generating a full, lengthy list of unnecessary search values slows down the operation by orders of magnitude. It eliminates that problem by only looking at those numbers that can combine with other numbers in a useful, "non-degenerate" way.

I'll see if there are any further optimizations and come back to this again. Where you see the literal values of 20 and 100 in the query those can be replaced by variables. The formula `n * (n + 1) / 2` evaluates to the nth triangular number while the one involving a square root determines the index of the largest triangular number less than or equal to the input.

The Nth triangular number is one formed by added up the integers from 1 to N. The sum of *any* set of consecutive numbers can be visualized as a triangular number plus a rectangular number. In the diagram below it's easy to see that incrementing the start of the range will increase the total by N (4 in this case.) This will be useful for determining the range of values with a length of N that could fill the groupings/slots:

```
 1-4       2-5       3-6        4-7         5-8
   *       * *       * **       * ***       * ****
  **      ** *      ** **      ** ***      ** ****
 ***     *** *     *** **     *** ***     *** ****
****    **** *    **** **    **** ***    **** ****
```

The very first grouping is easy to calculate as the largest triangular number less than the size of the maximum bracket. It must also be longer than any other grouping. The formula involving `floor()` and `sqrt()` can be found in references elsewhere but it simply calculates that N. The second grouping then must obviously connect to the first one so there's no point in considering lengths less than the maximal length but starting before the ending of the first one.

The first basically computes the Nth triangular number and determines how far you can slide a set of numbers with that length before overflowing the bracket size. The second CTE just explodes that data into what are effectively `(length, offset)` candidate pairs and applies some of the culling mentioned in the last paragraph.

The final complex filter is worth more explanation when I can come back but it looks to make sure that a candidate is filling as much space as possible For instance, there's no point in adding `{ 4, 5 }` when `{ 4, 5, 6 }` also fits within the total of 20.

```
with recursive data as (
    select
        n as len,
        (20 - n * (n + 1) / 2) / n + 1 as range,
        floor((sqrt(8 * 20 + 1) - 1) / 2)::int as maxlen
    from generate_series(2, floor((sqrt(8 * 20 + 1) - 1) / 2)::int) n
), candidates as (
    select ofs + 1 s, ofs + len e,
        row_number() over (partition by ofs order by len desc) as rnk
    from data cross join generate_series(0, (select max(range) - 1 from data)) ofs
    where ofs < range and (len = maxlen or ofs >= maxlen)
        and 20 - (ofs + 1 + (len - 1) / 2::float) * len < ofs + len + 1
), chain as (
    select * from candidates where s = 1
    union all
    select rc.* from chain c inner join candidates rc on rc.s = c.e + 1
)
select s, least(e, 100) as e from chain where s <= 100
union all
select n, n from generate_series((select max(e) + 1 from chain), 100) n
order by s;
```

Sample execution: https://dbfiddle.uk/1j0A2LWA

Query comparison. Larger inputs appear to scale well: https://dbfiddle.uk/s5hQKcKV

Comment: Some (more) explanation (or a link) might be needed on "triangular number", because SO is a site for programmers, not for mathematicians..... 

Comment: @Luuk [agreed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78093187/grouping-by-using-cumulative-sum/78093956#comment137675481_78093956) but I'd vote for an explanation on "termial function" or `n?`, for the same reason: Knuth tends to be more appealing to programmers.

Comment: +1 for continued improvements to the answer. Parametrising the query to wrap it in a function would not just make it comply with OP's updated requirements but also make it more readable, replacing anonymous constants with variable names. Which also makes it easier to maintain. Pushing this further to meet the current spec approaches [FizzBuzz EE](https://reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1mbd3s) effort, as it would have to spot and skip gaps in input arrays that are ordered but discontinuous, and look for intervals of monotonicity and apply this to its slices if the input is completely custom.

Comment: I didn't fully parameterize the query was because OP wasn't even specific about how this was going to be used. Yes, there's some potential to clean it up, which I would happily do with feedback. At this point there wasn't the slightest acknowledge for the multiple hours I did put into thinking about this. And it's not my job to take every question across somebody's definition of plug and play. The answer as it is is fully adaptable to use with variables, in a function, or on a different platform. For the goal of being an encylopedic reference you'd think we would favor generic answers.

Comment: The quote about real-life democracy applies to SO's variant of what would be democratic monarchy: it's pretty bad, but it's still the best system we've got. Answering is a pretty thankless task for the most part and the fact the accept check mark is entirely down to OP's personal choice, doesn't help, especially with low voting traffic and quality thereof. Best you can do is tag them and convince them to your answer, but that always feels rather demeaning and is seen as a territorial breach. My verbal appreciation of your work here is all solace I can offer in addition to the lonely vote

Comment: *~1000 times faster than accepted answer* is not true, tho. The function definition I have written executes `SELECT * FROM groups_up_to_sum(75, (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(n) FROM generate_series(1, 8000) AS T(n))) ORDER BY GroupNum;` (to take the series and grouping as you) in 28ms on dbfiddle. That is 3x slower than your definition, yes (but with extra flexibility and IMO better readability) but not 1000x, come on...

Comment: I agree that's a pointless number, but it's not entirely untrue - this one scales better and uses a shortcut to avoid doing any work in most of the range, so you *could* come up with a higher sample size where this one stays on sub-second exec times while the other one will sweat all the way up to 1000x. 8k isn't such sample and the comparison test isn't entirely fair/up to date. If the solution here was properly function-wrapped, parameterised to simplify benchmarks and made to return the required output format to make it apples-to-apples, that would be easier to demonstrate.

Comment: @Atmo, I linked to a result where the timing was roughly a ratio of about 1200. Granted that number won't apply to all inputs, it was still the principle that my contribution went fully ignored that had irritated me. I also don't know all the ins and out of PostGres. So I wanted to post something that worked rather than being dinged for a tangential issue with variable usage or some inconsequential nit.

Comment: @shawnt00 I have seen the ratio but my point was not about inputs... You have taken the query written to demonstrate the principle, ignoring the other. At most, I have written about some additional optimizations (stopping the recursion at half the target sum) but have not implemented it. Anyway, similar to your comment, "*it was still the principle that my contribution went fully ignored that had irritated me*", the fact you are doing that sort of cherry picking (take the slower query to get a higher ratio, and that is no small difference here) with my answer irritates me too. Fair?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect about contributions (not) being visible on this site, happens so often it is frustrating for me too sometimes. I even have a couple cases where the question was deleted after I spent 2h+ on the answer ([an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77613614/20143744)); I share the pain mate.

Comment: @Atmo, I get it. I could have written a simple cursor loop but the challenge of finding something efficient drew me in. (I really wanted to avoid the recursion too.) I spent several hours on this during an incredibly busy time when I really needed to be working on other things and mostly I got complaints that I should have done a while bunch of other steps too. I don't care about rep. Feedback is kinda nice though. (Also not changing the requirements...)